# Proof of x-coordinates of inflection point is $~\mu\pm\sigma~$ of probability density function of a normal distribution.

Tags: systems-of-equations, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

$$\begin{align}
f(x):= \underbrace{{1 \over \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma  }\exp \left(- {(x-\mu)^2 \over 2\sigma^2 } \right)}_{~~\text{pdf of normal distribution}~~ }  ~~\text{for}~~(-\infty <x < \infty) 
\end{align}$$

I want to prove that the inflection points of x-corrdinatess are $~ \mu\pm\sigma ~$

$$\begin{align}
{\mathrm{d}f \over \mathrm{d}x }&=- {(x-\mu) \over \sigma^2 }f(x)\\
{\mathrm{d^2}f \over \mathrm{d}x^2 }&=- {1 \over \sigma^2 }  \left\{ 1- \left({x-\mu \over \sigma } \right)^2 \right\}  f(x)\\
\end{align}$$

$~ \mu\pm\sigma ~$ are the only values each of which makes $~ f''(x) ~$ zero since $~ f(x)\in\mathbb{R_{>0}} ~$ is held for any $~ x ~$

Intuitively, it can be strongly asserted that $~ f(x)|_{x\in[\mu-\sigma,~\mu+\sigma]} ~$ is a concave function from the [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg) below.

[image]

Currently I've been struggling to understand that $~ f(x)|_{x<\mu-\sigma,~x>\mu+\sigma}~$is a convex function,since slopes of it seem too shallow.

Can anyone give me what I've been missing or some advice about it?

**ADD**

I've derived that $~f''\big|_{x>\mu+\sigma}>0~$ is held and this suggests that $~f''\big|_{x<\mu-\sigma}>0~$ is also satisfied because of a symmetry.

And the remaining problem is to derive $f''\big|_{x\in[\mu-\sigma,~\mu+\sigma]}<0~$is held.

Comment: Doesn't the sign of $f''$ tell you about the concavity and convexity of $f$?

Comment: Now I derived that $f''\big|_{x>\mu+\sigma}>0~$is satisfied.

Comment: Alternatively you can show that in a neighborhood of the inflection points $f'$ doesn't change sign.

Comment: @Icv I may look it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply $~x=\mu+\sigma+c~~\text{where}~~c\in\mathbb R_{>0} $ to the right side of $~ f(x) ~$

This can easily prove $~ f''\big|_{x>\mu+\sigma}>0 ~$

And about the concave section, apply $~x=\mu+\sigma-c~~\text{where}~~c\in\mathbb R_{>0}~\bigcap ~\mathbb R_{\leq \mu+\sigma} ~$

This can prove $~ f''\big|_{0\leq x<\mu+\sigma}<0 ~$

Since $~ f(x) ~$is an even function, finding out the inflection point of positive x-axis side is enough to achieve the given task.